# Pandas GrroupBy - get column with name "count"

Tags: python, pandas

I try to get count of each category in DataFrame as:

```
data = {'col_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','c'],'col_2': [3, 2, 1, 0, 4],'col3':[99,88,77,66,55]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df.groupby(['col_1']).count())


Output:

       col_2  col3
col_1             
a          1     1
b          1     1
c          2     2
d          1     1
```

Why there are two columns "col_2" and "col_3" and hot to get only one with name "count" ?

Wished output is :

```
  col_1        count     
    a          1     
    b          1
    c          2
    d          1
```

Comment: Why dont you use `df["col_1"].value_counts()`. It works!
Edit:-So value_counts() returns a Series containing counts of unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
print(df.groupby(['col_1'],as_index=False).agg(count=('col_2','count')))
```

**OR**

```
print(df.groupby(['col_1'],as_index=False).size().rename(columns={'size':'count'}))
```

Output:

```
col_1      count     
  a          1     
  b          1
  c          2
  d          1
```